# Where can I collaborate on JavaScript, similar to CodeHS

Tags: javascript, collaboration

Is there any website that we can use CodeHS Javascript on, while also allowing multiple users on the same console? I'm doing a highschool project that requires a collaborative website to work together on a program to show in class, but the only Javascipt that we know is the Javascript that CodeHS has. If there are none, are there any tips in learning the Javascript that we have to learn. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the founder of CodeHS, so hopefully I can help out a bit with your questions. We have an experimental feature to let you collaborate in real time on the CodeHS site, but that isn't rolled out yet to everyone. In terms of testing this with a friend, I just set up a JSFiddle link that you could use to collaborate here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jkeesh/bexz7c3d/

```
var circle = new Circle(50);
circle.setColor(Color.BLUE);
add(circle);

setTimer(animate, 100);

function animate(){
    circle.move(5, 5);
}
```

This is a short program that draws and moves a blue circle.

What I did (that you can do too!) is take a program from my sandbox, then click the "Embed" tab. On that tab it gives you the HTML and JavaScript you need to run it on your own page. I just set up this JS fiddle with that information.

What I did was add a canvas (so you can create your graphics) as well as include external JavaScript resources including jQuery and the CodeHS JavaScript library.

If you'd like to extend this with a friend you can click "fork" and then you have your own version.

For those who don't know what CodeHS is, it is a site to help teach coding to high schools and we have a JavaScript library that we use to help make some things easier. Full docs on that here: https://d14to6y4nub5k1.cloudfront.net/gulp/57e816d2f11c9f1627f0d84b85f8c2132674d70c/jsdoc/chs-js-lib/index.html

Hope that helps out!

Answer (score 1):

one of the CodeHS founders here--

Here are a few resources you can use to run CodeHS JavaScript outside of CodeHS.

1. Here's a link to the CodeHS Javascript library: https://d14to6y4nub5k1.cloudfront.net/gulp/d75f876caefad248c9b735ae6761a39c4c205490/chs-js-lib/chs.js

You can include that on any html page to get access to the library.

e.g. Include this on your html page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d14to6y4nub5k1.cloudfront.net/gulp/d75f876caefad248c9b735ae6761a39c4c205490/chs-js-lib/chs.js"></script>
```

2. visit https://codehs.com/docs to see documentation for all of the parts of the library
3. If you start the project on CodeHS in your sandbox, you can read this resource to embed your program on an HTML page: http://feedback.codehs.com/knowledgebase/articles/372002-how-can-i-use-my-code-outside-of-codehs

And feel free to reach out to our support team any time if you have questions.